# It deletes all my files when I try to change a word in my file in C

Tags: c, file

I want to change specific word in a file which has given by the user in C. here is a part of my code. (`b` is the path of my file.)
When I wrote `dosya = fopen(b,"w+");` I wanted it to read the old content, then delete it. Then the code starts and changes the word which doesn't have any problem. In the end I closed my file with `fclose(dosya);`. Then I wrote `dosya = fopen(b,"a+");` so it can add the new version of the content. If I don't write `"a+"` and write `"w+"` it only gets one line of the code because in my main function I filled my file with `fgets` which is filling it line by line.

```
while ((fgets(a, 1000, dosya)) != NULL)
{
  replaceWordInText(a,degis,son,b);
}
```

But if I try to fill it with `fputs` instead of `fgets` it doesn't fill. So I used `fgets`. When I use this code it works perfectly but then it deletes all my files in my university folder because it says it has some kind of virus I guess. What is the problem? What have I done wrong?

```
void replaceWordInText(const char *text, const char *oldWord, const char *newWord,char *b) {
   FILE *dosya;
   dosya = fopen(b,"w+");
   int i = 0, cnt = 0;
   int len1 = strlen(newWord);
   int len2 = strlen(oldWord);
   for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      if (strstr(&text[i], oldWord) == &text[i]) {
         cnt++;
         i += len2 - 1;
      }
   }
   char *newString = (char *)malloc(i + cnt * (len1 - len2) + 1);
   i = 0;
   while (*text) {
      if (strstr(text, oldWord) == text) {
         strcpy(&newString[i], newWord);
         i += len1;
         text += len2;
      }
      else
      newString[i++] = *text++;
   }
   fclose(dosya);
   dosya = fopen(b,"a+");
   fputs(newString,dosya);
}
```

Comment: In general, do not try to modify a file.  Instead, write the desired output to a new file and relink (rename) the file when you are done.  The final relinking can be done atomically, and greatly minimizes the risk of data corruption.

Comment: Please explain, in great detail, the `replaceWordInText` function you your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), room-mate, or a class-mate. Concentrate on the file functions, like what happens when you call `fopen(b,"w+")` ([a `fopen` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) might help you).

Comment: Check section 7.21.5.3 of https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf.  It clearly states what mode `w+` does to the data in the file.  In particular, "truncate to zero length"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if i write `fopen(b,"w+")` instead of a+, it only gets the last line in my content and changes the word i wanted it to change. but i want the full content, so i use a+ so it writes and changes all the lines but after it changes (in windows computer), in 10 seconds the virus program finds a virus and changes to the original version.  in my mac computer before it even changes it deletes the files immediately so i can't see if it's changed or not.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yeah i guess you're right i tried that too but i couldn't do it i guess i will give another shot to that one cause i can't do this one either. thanks for your help

Comment: The very first thing you do in the function is `dosya=fopen(b,"w+");`. That will erase the existing contents of the file. You should probably not have that. And you should close the file *after* you write to it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but i want it to read the content, delete it, do the changes in the content, then add to the file the changed content all over again. with w+ i made it read and delete the content, then i had to use a+ so i had to close it to don't get errors. unfortunately  if i add another `fclose(dosya)`to the end it doesn't change anything again

Comment: Also, you try to read from and write to the same file simultaneously, that will create a lot of problems. As mentioned, read from one file, write to another, and then rename the other afterward.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay i think that's the best way too thank you very much for your help i will try that 

Comment: strstr already searches a string, so your loop through every character is strange.

Comment: @stark it changes the word, that part doesn't have a problem. the problem is i can't write it in the file. i explained it in my other comment.